# Size issue for Report Chart in Lightning Custom Home Page

Tags: lightning-experience, report-chart, lightning-home-page

I created a Custom Home Page in Lightning App Builder with a few standard elements such as recent items, account insight, task, report chart etc.

The only issue I have found is regarding **report chart**. Is it possible to control the size of the chart. It looks very small and quite difficult to read.

[image]